# Check whether the same value is existing in array of objects in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have inputs and a data table. When user fill the inputs and click add button, those new values add to the table. But user can not add same values if the value is already added to the table (same dates and value). *Please find the screenshot below.*

[image]

I have no idea how to do this. I found Set method but it's not working as I expected.

**serviceFeeTableData** array stores the table data values as objects.

```
this.state = {
    periodFrom: new Date(),
    periodTo: new Date(),
    serviceFeeType: 'Percentage',
    serviceFee: '',
    refundableStatus: 'Refundable',

    serviceFeeTableData: []
};
```

Add button function

```
addNewServiceFee = () => {
        let resultData = [...this.state.serviceFeeTableData]

        let result = Array.from(new Set(resultData))
        return alert('Error! You have already added this value', result)
}
```

I need to check periodFrom date, periodTo date and serviceFee value is existing in the table record ( in the objecs of serviceFeeTableData ). If user already added that record to table, I need to show a error message. User can't add same exact record again and again. Only one serviceFee can add for the particular time period.

Input field values which is user entered, set to state.

addNewServiceFee function will take the state values and assign them to array as an object. I didn't add the code because of keep the code simple.

Comment: There's not enough code here to help you. Are you trying to grab e.target.value? What is e?

Comment: Please add more information to your question, from what I can see, the `result` variable is an object, you cant just put a set on an array of objects to make the entities unique. You need to actually compare values inside the object to determine uniqueness. Each object has a different location in memory so the `new Set` wouldn't filter entities

Comment: User can add a date period and some values by using input fields to the table. When user trying to add new record, I want to check that particular time period and the serviceFee value is already available (added) in that record and if it's available, user can't add that record. Basically can't allow to keep same values of objects more than one. Please refer the screenshot. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Array includes method if it's not nested object. Eg

```
var array1 = [1, 2, 3];

console.log(array1.includes(2));
//return true
```

If its nested object :

```
function checkObjectExist(obj, list) {

    return list.some(elem => elem === obj) //condition to check exist or not
}
```

**Note** : You have not clearly mentioned what data you want to check. I am assuming id here. So the code should be like this :

```
addNewServiceFee = (e) => {
        let resultData = [...this.state.serviceFeeTableData]

        let checkIsExist = resultData.some(data => data.id === "testingcondition");
        if(checkIsExist){
            let result = resultData.filter(data => data.id === "testingcondition");
           return alert('Error! You have already added this value', result)
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looping the array and find whether same values are there. If not, add the new record. If yes, notify an error.

```
let dateFormat = require('dateformat');
for (let a = 0; a < serviceFeeTableData.length; a++) {
    let periodFrom = dateFormat(new Date(serviceFeeTableData[a].periodFrom), 'dd-mmm-yyyy')
    let periodTo = dateFormat(new Date(serviceFeeTableData[a].periodTo), 'dd-mmm-yyyy')

    if (periodFrom === obj1.periodFrom && periodTo === obj1.periodTo) {
        statedate = false;
        break;
    }
}

if (statedate) {
    serviceFeeTableData.push(obj1)
} else {
    this.notifyError("Selected dates are overlapping with the existing periods. Please select a different period.");
}
}
```